# Push notification for gmail in iOS app

Tags: ios, gmail, gmail-imap, gmail-api

For an iOS app which connects to a user's mailbox, i'm looking for a reliable way to send the user a push notification when new mail is available. (Without polling, of course).

If needed, I'm ok with setting up a server that will receive a push from gmail and re-send it as an iOS push.
It is not ok however if the user has to configure anything special in their account for the push to work.

Any advice or reference to a library (or external service) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: did you got some solution for the same

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there currently is no mechanism to receive updates automatically when new mail arrives. I would recommend logging an enhancement request for push notification support in the Gmail API in the [Apps API issue tracker](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/list). In lieu of this, you can minimize resource utilization by only doing a full sync once, and then keeping track of the history id and doing only partial syncs from that point.

Answer (score 0):

Google have added official support for push notifications on mailbox changes via the watch() call.

Usage is documented here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#getting_gmail_mailbox_updates